# Cucumber: Creating a step definition that depends on another step

Tags: cucumber

I need to setup a cascading "Given" -- one factory that belongs_to the factory before it ... in plain rspec, I'd create he first factory, then take it's ID and pass it to the next factory.

> @widget = Factory(:something)
>   @otherthing = Factory(:other, :widget_id => @widget.id)

What's the best way to do this in a step definition? My scenario says: "Given a widget AND a thing", but that creates two steps that don't seem to know anything about the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach as RSpec. A step can access instance variables set in a different step.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy says - steps within a scenario can share state with each other through instance variables (because each *scenario* is executed within a new instance of the `World` object).

In your case I'd write something like:

```
Given /^a widget$/ do
    @the_widget = Factory(:something)
end

Given /^a thing$/ do
    raise "Must create a widget first!" if @the_widget.nil? # In case the scenario author forgets the widget-creation step

    @the_otherthing = Factory(:other, :widget_id => @widget.id)
end
```